# Create a Diffie Hellman Object from hex encoded p and g parameters

Tags: node.js, cryptography, parameter-passing, diffie-hellman

Om my application I receive the [diffie hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) p and g parameters via an XMPP message for example:

```
<message to="admin@0.0.0.0/4fjd0564xh" from="keygen1546701622316@conference.0.0.0.0/admin" type="groupchat"><body>
<x xmlns="http://pcmagas.tk/gkePlusp#intiator_key">
    <p>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</p>

    <g>02</g>
   </x>
</body>
</message>
```

As Node.js [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_diffiehellman) module says you can Initiate a Diffie Hellman either via an interger providing the `g` parameter length:

```
const alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048);
```

Or via provided `p` and `g` parameters:

```
const bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(alice.getPrime(), alice.getGenerator());
```

But on my stream the keys are encoded as a hex string thus how I can convert them to the appropriate object in order to make the appropriate `diffieHellman` Object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the following code shows the functions `getPrime` and `getGenerator` generate a `Buffer` object:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const k1 = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048);
const p = k1.getPrime();
const g = k1.getGenerator();
// Outputs true,true
console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(p), Buffer.isBuffer(g));
```

So you can generate a Diffie Hellman Object from a hex encoded strings via:

```
//pInHex,gInHex hex encoded p and g
const p = Buffer.from(pInHex,'hex');
const g = Bugger.from(gInHex,'hex');
const dh = crypto.createDiffieHellman(p, g);
```

As you can see according to [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) you can create buffers from hex-encoded strings.